# SELECT from a list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, unpivot

So it is pretty straight forward to do:

```
Select Val from MyTable where Val not in ('100','200','300'....)
```

1. How do I write a query so that I select values from the list. eg how do I do something like  `Select * from ('100','200','300'....)` so that the output is:

   ```
   100    
   200    
   300    
   ...
   ```
2. Further, How do I do something like `select * from ('100','200','300'....) that are not in MyTable.Val` column?

Comment: Is `Val` a string type (`'100'`) or numeric type (`100`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I do something like select * from ('100','200','300'....) that are not in MyTable.Val

You can use `values()` to build a derived table that contains the list of values, and then `not exists` to filter on those that cannot be found in the table:

```
select v.*
from (values (100), (200), (300)) v(val)
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t where t.val = v.val)
```

Comment: Is there a benefit in `where not exists (select 1 from mytable t where t.val = v.val)` instead of `where v.val not in (select Val from MyTable)` ?

Comment: @VaibhavGarg: yes. First, `not exists` is null-safe, while `not in` is not (if any `val` in `mytable` is `null`, weird things happen). Second, performance of `not exists` is generally superior (especially if you have an index on `mytable(val)`).

Answer (score 1):

Part 1

```
Select * from (values ('100'),('200'),('300')) v(val);
```

Part 2

```
Select * 
from
  (values ('100'),('200'),('300')) v(val)
where not exists (select 1 from myTable t where t.val=v.val);
```